# using unordered_map to implement adjacency list for graph representation

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, adjacency-list

I want to implement adjacency list for graph using unordered_map. Selecting unordered_map because it can give me O(1) time to access neighboring vertices by a given vertex. So my idea is to define the unordered_map as below:

```
using namespace std;

class node {};
class edge {};  
typedef vector<edge*> edges_t;
typedef unordered_map<node*, edges_t*> graph_t;
```

I use the pointer of class node as the key of unordered_map because using node object directly would require a customized std::hash implementation. The major issue of using pointer is memory management. I need to free the allocated memory explicitly.

Can unique_ptr be used here to ease the memory managment? or any better solution to suggest ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why not have `node` contain an `edges_t` thingy?

Comment: @n.m.: you would still need an adjacency map (probably) because edges link two vertices (unless you accept duplication, but it has its own issues).

Comment: why not using `unordered_multimap` and ditch the `edges_t` thingsy entirly

Comment: @MatthieuM. Does adjacency map let you get rid of duplication? How?

Comment: @Valerij Because an edge is not a pair of vertices.

Comment: @n.m. what than? because i learned in graph theory 101 a graph is a $(V,E\subseteq V\cross V)$ where $V$ are the vertexes and $E$ the edges.

Comment: @n.m.: because, as represented here, the adjacency map contain a `std::vector<edge*>` and thus the pointed-to edge can be shared by both sides (in case it has properties, like a direction, a weight, etc...). Obviously, you still have to index it from both nodes, but it reduces the duplication-aware functions to those that add or remove an edge.

Comment: @Valerij Graph-theoretic concepts are wonderful. In real life we need labeled edges, weighed edges, multi-edges and what not.

Comment: @MatthieuM. "the adjacency map contain a std::vector<edge*> and thus the pointed-to edge can be shared by both sides". Exactly the same is true about `std::vector<edge*>` contained directly in a vertex.

Comment: @n.m. graph theory got those cases covered aswell, like $weight:E\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ for weight (can be a function can be a map<pair<V,V>,int>) and so on

Comment: @Valerij It is not always convenient to implement mathematical concepts with similarly named C++ constructs. A class that stores a pair of vertices and associated data is a perfectly valid way to implement a mathematical concept of "map that sends a graph edge to its label".

Answer (score 1):

Ownership policy is indeed an issue, you have a few possibilities:

- if a clear owner exists, `std::unique_ptr` is the best choice (see [this example](http://ideone.com/UEVzqS))
- if there are multiple possible owners, you can either break the symmetry and introduce one or defer to `std::shared_ptr` (beware of cycles)

Breaking the symmetry can be as simple as introducing a `std::deque<node>` that will contain the nodes and take pointers inside that container. Likewise, a `std::deque<edge>` would solve the ownership issue for the edges.

Comment: "beware of cycles". That's right, `std::shared_ptr` in an arbitrary graph supplies most of the raw pointer safety combined with all of the the reference-counting performance.

Comment: @n.m.: It depends what it's used for. Since edges have no reason to point to other edges, `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<edge>>` could be an apt container. If edges start pointing to nodes and nodes to edges, then indeed you have a cycle forming. It all boils down to how wisely they are used, in the end.

Comment: Well, if edges and nodes do not point to each other *somehow*, how do you traverse the graph? Some of these pointers should not be shared_ptrs, that's all. They may be weak pointers, raw pointers, or entries in a map.

Answer (score 0):

In a recent program, in my Graph class,I created a new data type called Map which I defined as:

typedef unordered_map, VertexHash, VertexEquals> Map

where Vertex objects are nodes; Edges objects are an origin Vertex, destination Vertex and double distance; VertexHash is a class or struct with an overloaded ( ) to hash Vertex objects ; and VertexEquals is a class or stuct which determines if two Verrte. Objects are equal used the overloaded ==. Each Graph object has a vector which holds a list of Vertex objects and and a Map variable which holds the graph data.